# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docxtpl'

Tags: python, python-docx

I know that this is a simple question...I have tried going through a few of the other questions related to `ModuleNotFoundError` w/Pycharm and I tried uninstalling `docxptl` via `pip` but to no avail.

Looking in the library i see `docxtpl` so I am a bit confused.

I also uninstalled and reinstalled `lxml` via `pip` as that seemed to cause some issues with `docxptl` with other people with `docxtpl`

code:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
```

error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docxtpl'
```

Comment: Can you import all other packages except that one? Also, can you see this package in the output of the `pip freeze` command?

Comment: Are you using venv? In any case, you can go to settings>project:xxx>python interpreter and check if your package is listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow my steps carefully:

- Go to PyCharm settings
- Search for `Python Interpreter`
- Click on the `+` icon in the window
- Then search for `docxtpl` in the new window and then click on it
- Then select Install Package

**Full fledged tutorial here:** https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

[image]